# Issue with "10010 TXN_PARTITION_STATE_UNMATCH" Error in GridDB During Client Request Execution

Tags: cluster-computing, failover, griddb

I am encountering a persistent issue while executing client requests in GridDB, with the error code "10010 TXN_PARTITION_STATE_UNMATCH." The GridDB version in use is "5.1.0-39692 CE," and the environment is a WSL machine.

```py
from griddb_python import GridDB

cluster = GridDB.cluster("my_cluster_name")
try:
    gridstore = cluster.get_store("my_container_name", GridDB.GS_WRITE_ONLY)
    gridstore.start_transaction()

    query = "INSERT INTO my_table_name (column1, column2) VALUES ('value1', 'value2')"
    gridstore.query(query)

    gridstore.commit()

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
    gridstore.rollback()

finally:
    cluster.close()
```

I thought one identified possible cause is that the cluster may be in the process of being re-configured.

The suggested countermeasure is to run the application again. Additionally, if a value other than 0 is specified in the failover timeout time, the client should automatically run the application again.

Despite implementing this countermeasure, the problem persists. I'm seeking guidance on whether there are additional steps I can take to troubleshoot and resolve this issue in the context of GridDB. Specifically, are there any specific configurations or checks that need to be considered during a cluster re-configuration?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Python API: https://griddb.org/python_client/PythonAPIReference.htm

you're using lots of methods that don't exist or are using those that do incorrectly. Please change your code and see if the error persists